# Apart from forms and AJAX, is there any other way to make a POST request in Spring MVC?

Tags: java, jsp, spring-mvc

I have a request to make where I send in various parameters of an object. Right now, I send them through a GET request but that, as you know, shows all the values in the URL. In order to avoid it, I want to make it a POST request.

I am aware of 2 ways to make POST requests - form submit where `method='POST'` and AJAX. But since the request I will be calling returns a view, AJAX will not be a good idea. If I use the form method, there will be at least 8 object parameters which will have to be hidden. This is what I have now:

```
<form method="POST" action="/submit" modelAttribute="objName">
    <input type="hidden" name="val1" value="val1" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val2" value="val2" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val3" value="val3" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val4" value="val4" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val5" value="val5" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val6" value="val6" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val7" value="val7" />
    <input type="hidden" name="val8" value="val8" />
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Is there a better way to do this? Because it creates a lot of hidden HTML markup and it doesn't feel like the ideal way to be going about the situation.

Thanks in advance. If there is anything wrong with the question, please let me know and I will make changes(new to SO) :)

Comment: Spring MVC has a model and view object. Refer http://docs.spring.io/autorepo/docs/spring-framework/3.0.x/api/org/springframework/web/servlet/ModelAndView.html. Ajax is the best fit for the case. What you return depends on the controller.

Comment: @user3632894 My controller(the POST request in question) returns a ModelAndView object precisely. But when I make an AJAX call to it, the response received is the entire HTML markup of the view page returned. The page does not change. Is there something I am missing about AJAX?

Comment: A lot depends on return type and headers. If you are returning html, have content header as application/html

Comment: @user3632894 could you elaborate with an example please? Feel free to write a reply.